# how to parse or convert

Tags: c#

Is there easyer way to parse in c# then this:

```
float temp;
if (float.TryParse(quantity.ToString(), out temp))
{
     noteProduct.Quantity = temp;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's so difficult about that?

Comment: the datatype can be anything. The problem with this method is that it is complicated. I am looking something in one line.

Comment: Float is a horrible datatype for a product quantity. Consider `int` or `decimal` instead.

Comment: @ Joren: what is wrong with float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. This is more easier to use instead of declaring temp variables and make if statements.

```
   public class Parsers
    {
        private Parsers() { }

        public static void SetLong(ref long item, object value)
        {
            long temp;
            if (value != null && long.TryParse(value.ToString(), out temp)) { item = temp; }
        }

        public static void SetDateTime(ref DateTime item, object value)
        {
            DateTime temp;
            if (value != null && DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out temp)) { item = temp; }
        }

        public static void SetInt(ref int item, object value)
        {
            int temp;
            if (value != null && int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out temp)) { item = temp; }
        }

        public static void SetString(ref string item, object value)
        {
            if (value != null) { item = value.ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse` is the best way, if you want to avoid possible exceptions.

If you are certain that `quantity` will always be a valid float you can simply use `Parse`:

```
noteProduct.Quantity = float.Parse(quantity.ToString());
```

However, this will throw an exception if `quantity.ToString()` is not a valid float.

Comment: I want to avoid exception handling on the parsing.

Comment: @Naor - The you _have_ to use `TryParse` and the pattern you have posted.

Comment: I don't like the idea of creating many temp variables when I need to make many parsings.

Comment: @Naor - then reuse the same temp variable.

Comment: I can reuse temp variable with the same type. Bu I made many parsing with different types..

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use `float.Parse("string")` - but it will throw exception if it can't parse it.

For me this is good and safe way of parsing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, yes there are easier ways, but that doesn't mean you should necessarily use them. Easier does not always mean better. In this example I'd actually recommend you make your parsing *more* complicated - by making it culture sensetive..

```
float temp;
if (Single.TryParse(quantity.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurentCulture, out temp)
{
    noteProduct.Quantity = temp;
}
```